# C# Sudoku puzzle solver gets stuck while trying to backtrack to avoid bad values

Tags: c#, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I'm trying to get better at understanding recursion and I'm working on a program that is supposed to solve Sudoku puzzles by iterating over each cell in the puzzle and trying a value out of a list of possible values. After it drops in a value, it checks if doing so has solved the puzzle. If not, it continues on adding values and checking if doing so has solved the puzzle. There's a problem, though - I can see in my app's GUI that it eventually gets confused or stuck and starts attempting the same value insertion over and over. For example, here's an example of some logging that shows it being stuck:

```
Possible values: F
Old string: 086251B7D93+++C4
New string: 086251B7D93F++C4
```

As you can see, it's looking to see what value could possibly go into the cell after the 3 without violating the row, column, or box constraints. The only possible value is F, so it places it in there. But then it does the same thing over and over, and randomly starts attempting to edit other cells in other lines even though there are still +'s in this first row. It'll try to edit a row a few rows down, and it'll swap between doing that and then attempting this same scenario with the F repeatedly until the app crashes because of what Visual Studio thinks is a ContextSwitchDeadlock error.

What have I missed in my algorithm? Here is my method that tries to fill in the Sudoku puzzle:

```
public bool SolveGrid(List<Row> rows, List<Box> boxes)
{
    textBox1.Clear()
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(row.content + "\n");
    }

    if (ValidatorAgent.IsGridSolved(rows, boxes))
    {
        textBox2.AppendText("Success!");
        successGrid = rows; 
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        foreach (var cell in row.content)
        {
            if (cell.Equals('+'))
            {
                var possibleValues = availableValues.Where(v => !ValidatorAgent.AreGridConstraintsBreached(cell, v, row, rows, boxes)).ToList();
                if (!possibleValues.Any())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Possible values: ");
                possibleValues.ForEach(v => Console.Write(v.ToString()));

                List<char> values = new List<char>();
                possibleValues.ForEach(v => values.Add(v));

                foreach (var possibleValue in values)
                {
                    var oldContent = row.content;
                    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(row.content);
                    var indexToChange = row.content.IndexOf(cell);
                    stringBuilder[indexToChange] = possibleValue;

                    Console.WriteLine("Old string: " + oldContent);
                    Console.WriteLine("New string: " + stringBuilder.ToString());
                    var alteredPuzzle = BuilderAgent.BuildPuzzleCopy(rows);
                    alteredPuzzle.Single(r => r.yCoord == row.yCoord).content = stringBuilder.ToString();
                    var newBoxes = BuilderAgent.BuildBoxes(alteredPuzzle);
                    SolveGrid(alteredPuzzle, newBoxes);
                }
            }
        }
   }

   return false;
}
```

I am pretty confident that my IsGridSolved method works correctly because I've tested it on puzzle solutions and found that it reported whether or not a puzzle was already solved. I've also tested my AreGridConstraintsBreached method with unit tests and also by eyeballing the results of the code, so I'm fairly confident in that code. It basically checks whether or not a cell's potential value is redundant due to the relevant row, column, or box already having that value. In Sudoku, when you place a value you need to make sure that the value 1) doesn't already exist in the row 2) doesn't already exist in the column and 3) doesn't already exist in the small box surrounding the cell. I feel like I'm missing something obvious in the algorithm itself, and that it isn't backtracking properly. I've tried fiddling with the SolveGrid method so that it takes in a list of validValues that are based off of the availableValues, with some pruning so that failed values are pruned out after each recursive call to SolveGrid but that didn't do anything besides keep the puzzle from even getting as far as it currently does. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: How confidant are you that `BuilderAgent.BuildPuzzleCopy` is doing a proper deep clone of the puzzle in its current state?

Comment: I usually get stuck while solving a sudoku.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Fairly confident but I will confirm my assumption about it. Is it safe to say that you didn't notice anything wrong with the algorithm as a whole, and that is why you're asking about that method? Maybe the error is something deeper like in BuilderAgent.BuildPuzzleCopy or somewhere else?

Comment: @BradleyUffner After looking at the logic, I can confirm that I'm very confident it's working properly. It's pretty straightforward cloning. It just iterates over each row in the old puzzle and adds it to a new collection of rows representing the new puzzle. Then it returns the new collection of rows.

Comment: 1, you must not ignore the result of the recursion call to `SolveGrid`

Comment: @JürgenRöhr Do you mean towards the end of the method? What exactly should I do differently?

Comment: I think he's saying that you need to check the return value.  If it returns true, then it found a solution and you need to stop searching.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't think that's the reason for the repeated failed backtracking. After making that change, I'm seeing the same result. And the method checks for success right away, so there's not much difference between checking at the beginning of the method and checking the return value of the recursive call towards the end of the method.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Stop fiddling with the code and start running it through a debugger. Find a case that does something wrong. Run it through the debugger. Before each step, make a prediction of what the code *should* do at that step. Then do the step and see if your prediction came true. At some point it will not. That's where the bug is.

Comment: This series of articles may be of interest to you. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/graph-colouring/

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks Eric! Really appreciate the links. Huge fan of your blog.